# How to convert type to byte array golang

Tags: arrays, go, comparison, slice

How to Convert Type of one kind to byte array

Here is the working example

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Signature [5]byte

const (
    /// Number of bytes in a signature.
    SignatureLength = 5
)

func main() {

    var bytes0to64 Signature = SignatureFromBytes([]byte("Here is a string.........."))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(bytes0to64))

    res := bytes.Compare([]byte("Test"), bytes0to64)
    if res == 0 {
        fmt.Println("!..Slices are equal..!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("!..Slice are not equal..!")
    }

}

func SignatureFromBytes(in []byte) (out Signature) {
    byteCount := len(in)
    if byteCount == 0 {
        return
    }

    max := SignatureLength
    if byteCount < max {
        max = byteCount
    }

    copy(out[:], in[0:max])
    return
}
```

In Go lang defined

`type Signature [5]byte`

So this is expected

```golang
var bytes0to64 Signature = SignatureFromBytes([]byte("Here is a string.........."))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(bytes0to64))
```

It just output the Type to

`main.Signature`

This is correct, now I want to get the byte array from this for the next level of processing and get a compilation error

```
./prog.go:23:29: cannot use bytes0to64 (type Signature) as type []byte in argument to bytes.Compare

Go build failed.
```

The error is right only there is a mismatch on comparison. Now how should i convert the Signature type to byte array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Signature` is a byte array, you may simply [slice](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) it:

```
bytes0to64[:]
```

This will result in a value of `[]byte`.

Testing it:

```
res := bytes.Compare([]byte("Test"), bytes0to64[:])
if res == 0 {
    fmt.Println("!..Slices are equal..!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("!..Slice are not equal..!")
}
res = bytes.Compare([]byte{72, 101, 114, 101, 32}, bytes0to64[:])
if res == 0 {
    fmt.Println("!..Slices are equal..!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("!..Slice are not equal..!")
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UYmauaikj4A)):

```
!..Slice are not equal..!
!..Slices are equal..!
```